# How to install network drivers offline

Tags: drivers, apt, internet, adapter, apt-offline

In my Ubuntu 22.04 system unable to get internet.
I think this is due no drivers installed to get internet. There is no wifi driver, no Bluetooth driver & no modules to get ethernet or wired connection.so,no way to access internet at all.

No Bluetooth, No WiFi, No wired data from phone.

Then, I this code executed the following code with Ubuntu iso:

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
cd~
sudo mount – o loop [name of installation ISO file].iso
```

Then I launched Software Updater and checked the cdrom iso checkbox and I went to the *Additional drivers* tab, but the tab says "no additional drivers available". How can I get back the internet in my device?

Image references:

1. Results of `sudo lshw -C network` :

   [image]
2. Results of `iwconfig` :

   [image]
3. `systemctrl: command not found` :

   [image: Shows]
4. Bluetooth is not turned on.

   [image]
5. Bluetooth is not turned on.

   [image]
6. list of services includes with network in its name.

   [image: list of services NO_PUBKEY]

Comment: You don't need drivers for this hardware. It is unclear how did this happen. Is it a new installation?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't post pictures of the terminal with text in them. Always copy the text from the terminal and [paste in directly in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1454118/edit) and format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} above the edit window.

Comment: The command is `systemctl`, not `systemctrl`.

Comment: This is happened at an update. It happened after an updated some selected checkboxes that I was checked on the Software updater. Kindly help to back the internet. @Pilot6

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu and finish the upgrade. Probably the upgrade was incomplete.

Comment: Thank @Pilot6. Everything is alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some kernel upgrade was incomplete. Kernel modules are not installed. This hardware doesn't need any additional drivers.

Boot from a previous kernel using `grub` menu and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```